# Binding System.Windows.Media.Color to TextBlock.Foreground?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, colors

When I do this I get:

> "Cannot create default converter to
>   perform 'one-way' conversions between
>   types 'System.Windows.Media.Color' and
>   'System.Windows.Media.Brush'. Consider
>   using Converter property of Binding."

Anyone knows how to do this?

Why can't WPF convert this automatically as I am using WPF colors, not System.Drawing.Color.

EDIT:

Xaml code:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Info">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Info, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="{Binding MessageColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Could you please show us the XAML in which you are setting the color?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default TypeConverter for the Brush type, does not support Color (even the WPF version). It only supports converting to/from strings.

You would have to create a custom IValueConverter that takes a Color and returns a SolidColorBrush.

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if (!(value is Color))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Value must be a Color");
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, after writing this, how will I use it? Is it gonna be used in xaml or actual code of the Color property (MessageColor)?

Comment: @Joan - You would use it in your binding like so "{Binding MessageColor, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}". You would need to add the xmlns to your CLR namespace, then add ColorToBrushConverter as a resource somewhere above where it's used (i.e. <myns:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToBrushConverter" /> )

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't figure out the correct namespace. Do you mean the namespace that is top most for the WPF app? Because using that didn't work, I already had it defined in xaml btw.

Comment: @Joan - [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx#Mapping_To_Custom_Classes_and_Assemblies) is an example. Notice how the xmlns:custom maps to the CLR namespace that the converter is defined in? The assembly portion is optional, if in the same assembly (i.e. xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:SDKSample")

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but I got fooled by the xaml editor outlining ColorToBrushConverter. But when I compiled it went away. Shouldn't it know that I had the type already? Also where do you think is the best place to store these kinds of converters for a WPF app?

Comment: @Joan - There used to be problems like that when referencing things in the same assembly, but I thought that was fixed. It may have just needed you to recompile.

Comment: @Joan - As for where to put it, it really depends on your project. Typically, they'd go in a shared assembly, if they are reusable by various parts of your application.

Comment: Thanks CodeNaked, that makes sense.